# What's the easiest way to debug an ActionScript class file?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, debugging, flash-builder

I'm currently using FlashBuilder to edit ActionScript 3.0 class files. I can't run the debugger in Flash Builder because the classes are actually built around the Flash Authoring Tool.

Flash Auth Tool has a lousy debugger (IMO) and it only allows breakpoints for inline Timeline scripting.

So basically I'm stuck without a debugger (that can use breakpoints).

How can I start using the Flash Builder debugger, while sticking to the .fla environment?

Or... how can I convert my .fla file into something Flash Builder can use (some MXML perhaps?)

Any help greatly appreciated..

Comment: I agree the Flash Authoring tool's debugger is comparatively wimpy, but it does support setting breakpoints in AS3 files -- just open the file in it, and click in the margin to set the breakpoint, then run with debugging (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER)

Comment: Aha, why didn't I think of that? Cheers man.

Comment: You might also check out [this link](http://flashauthoring.blogspot.com/2010/06/using-flash-builder-4-debugger-to-debug.html). You can debug in Flash Builder with a bit of work, but only AS3 files (which I believe is what your question pertained to). Additionally, if you have Flash Builder installed on your computer, you can set Flash CS5 to use it for Actionscript files automatically under Preferences (or perhaps Options if you're on Windows), Actionscript, Class Editor. You may already be doing this, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best friend in that case is to use copious logging. The `trace` function can be used for such a purpose, however  it doesn't support configuration, logging levels, etc. You might want to use one of the many logging frameworks for ActionScript or implement your own for such a purpose.